# How do I break apart a processed value and display last value from twig process?

Tags: twig

Using a print template in Lightspeed software, my "description" variable is being compiled of 3 variable values and passed to me.

I need to break these apart and display only Last value.

```
<p class="description">
    {% if hide_description == false %}
        {{ Label.Item.description | strreplace('_',' ') }}
    {% endif %}
</p>
```

Current output is: "Shirt Blue Large"

I tried:

```
{% filter last %}
    {{ Label.Item.description|strreplace('_',' ') }}
{% endfilter %}
```

and this is giving me an error.

I need output to be just "Large", any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [split](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) and [last](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/last.html) filter, as example:

```
{{ Label.Item.description|split('_')|last }}
```

See [this working fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/9xmcr1)

Hope this help